# How do I disable a SwiftUI NavigationView list item row on load?

Tags: swiftui, listitem, navigationview

I have an array of objects (employees) that I am displaying in a navigationview. Each object has a boolean property called "Active". If the employee is active I want the navigationlink for that list item to work as it normally would but if the employee is not active then I want that list item to be disabled so that the navigationlink or any swipe actions do not work. This is my code:

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        CustomSearchBar(searchText: $searchText, searchCategory: $searchCategory)
        ForEach(Employees) { person in
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DisplayDetails().environmentObject(person)) {
                    ListItem().environmentObject(person)
                }
            }
            .swipeActions(edge: .leading, content: {
                Button {
                    Employees.toggleArchiveFlag(for: person.id)
                } label: { 
                    Label("Archive", systemImage: !person.archived ? "square.and.arrow.down" : "trash")
                }
                .tint(!person.archived ? .blue : .red)
            })
            .disabled(!person.active)
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Current Employees")
    .padding(.horizontal,-15) // remove the padding that the list adds to the screen
}
```

What ends up happing is that when the view initially loads everything is enabled regardless of each employee's active status. But if I click any of the navigationlinks to load the "DisplayDetails" detailed view and then return back to the main navigationview OR if I click on any of the searchbar toggles or use the searchbar to filter my list of people then the view updates and the correct people are disabled.

It is almost as if the statement ".disabled(!person.active)" is being called too late. If that is the case then where should I be calling it? I have tried moving that statement in the following places:

- The closing bracket of the Zstack. But this does nothing
- Right below the "ListItem().environmentObject(person)" statement but this still shows the same behavior as mentioned earlier and when the navigationlink is eventually disabled then the swipeactions are still enabled.

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I think you will find the problem stems from the part of the view that you are not showing us.

Comment: works well in my tests. How do you `load/setup` your `Employees` when the view starts?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the issue was with the logic that set the person.active boolean value not with the presentation of the navigation view items. Thanks.